# NullPointerException when loading FXML file

Tags: javafx-8, fxml, fxmlloader

So, Ive done it many times without problem and yet this time when I moved fxml and its controller from one project to another I cannot load it. Directory to fxml is fine, directory  to controller in fxml file is also good, and I dont see why theres a problem to load it.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" prefHeight="340.0" prefWidth="230.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.controller.tomaszm.SpokenNumbersController">
   <center>
      <Pane prefHeight="389.0" prefWidth="241.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Pane layoutY="233.0" prefHeight="75.0" prefWidth="244.0" style="-fx-background-color: linear-gradient( from 0.0% 0.0% to 100.0% 100.0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.1034482792019844) 0.0, rgba(241,255,20,0.2068965584039688) 100.0);">
               <children>
                  <CheckBox layoutX="5.0" layoutY="55.0" mnemonicParsing="false" opacity="0.8" text="Test me when finished" />
                  <ToggleButton fx:id="toggbuttSTART" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="5.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#toggbuttSTARTAction" opacity="0.94" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="230.0" text="START">
                     <cursor>
                        <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                     </cursor>
                     <effect>
                        <InnerShadow height="35.83" radius="21.119999999999997" width="50.65" />
                     </effect>
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                     </font>
                  </ToggleButton>
               </children>
            </Pane>
            <AnchorPane layoutY="145.0" prefHeight="88.0" prefWidth="245.0" style="-fx-background-color: linear-gradient( from 0.0% 0.0% to 100.0% 100.0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.10000000149011612) 0.0, rgba(6,56,255,0.30000000298023224) 100.0);">
               <children>
                  <CheckBox fx:id="checkExtra" layoutX="5.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#checkExtraAction" opacity="0.96" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="230.0" text="Make extra breaks">
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="15.0" left="4.0" top="1.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </CheckBox>
                  <Pane fx:id="breaksPane" disable="true" layoutY="32.0" prefHeight="56.0" prefWidth="230.0">
                     <children>
                        <ComboBox fx:id="comboboxEach" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="90.0" promptText="each" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="comboboxExtraInterval" layoutX="116.0" layoutY="20.0" onAction="#checkExtraAction" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="90.0" promptText="interval" />
                        <Label layoutX="5.0" text="Cycle lenght:">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Italic" size="12.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <Label layoutX="116.0" layoutY="2.0" text="Delay:">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Italic" size="12.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                     </children>
                  </Pane>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="68.0" prefWidth="245.0" style="-fx-background-color: linear-gradient( from 0.0% 0.0% to 100.0% 100.0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.10000000149011612) 0.0, rgba(255,0,0,0.22000000298023224) 100.0);">
               <children>
                  <ComboBox fx:id="comboboxInterval" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="27.0" opacity="0.8" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="152.0" promptText="interval" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="8.0" />
                  <Label layoutX="5.0" layoutY="6.0" opacity="0.9" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Interval:" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="7.0">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <Pane layoutY="68.0" prefHeight="77.0" prefWidth="247.0" style="-fx-background-color: linear-gradient( from 0.0% 0.0% to 100.0% 100.0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.10000000149011612) 0.0, rgba(48,213,48,0.30000000298023224) 100.0);">
               <children>
                  <Slider fx:id="sliderCountdown" layoutX="2.0" layoutY="27.0" majorTickUnit="10.0" max="500.0" minorTickCount="0" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="179.0" showTickLabels="true" showTickMarks="true" snapToTicks="true" value="100.0" />
                  <Button fx:id="buttPlus" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="177.0" layoutY="25.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttPlusAction" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="31.0" style="-fx-background-insets: 4;" text="+" textFill="RED">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="14.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button fx:id="buttMinus" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="201.0" layoutY="25.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttMinusAction" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="31.0" style="-fx-background-insets: 4;" text="–" textFill="RED">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="14.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Label layoutX="5.0" layoutY="6.0" opacity="0.9" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="74.0" text="Countdown:">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label fx:id="labCountdown" layoutX="81.0" layoutY="6.0" opacity="0.9" text="100" textFill="RED" />
               </children>
            </Pane>
            <Separator layoutY="310.0" opacity="0.5" prefHeight="3.0" prefWidth="241.0" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </center>
   <top>
      <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Options">
            <items>
                  <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Language">
                     <items>
                        <RadioMenuItem fx:id="radiomenuPolish" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#selectLanguageAction" selected="true" text="Polski">
                           <toggleGroup>
                              <ToggleGroup fx:id="languageGroup" />
                           </toggleGroup>
                        </RadioMenuItem>
                        <RadioMenuItem fx:id="radiomenuEnglish" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#selectLanguageAction" text="English" toggleGroup="$languageGroup" />
                        <RadioMenuItem fx:id="radiomenuDeutsch" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#selectLanguageAction" text="Deutsch" toggleGroup="$languageGroup" />
                        <RadioMenuItem fx:id="radiomenuChinesse" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#selectLanguageAction" text="Chinesse" toggleGroup="$languageGroup" />
                     </items>
                  </Menu>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
   <bottom>
      <HBox opacity="0.6" prefHeight="10.0" prefWidth="241.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label prefHeight="4.0" prefWidth="74.0" text="Counted digits: ">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Cambria" size="11.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label fx:id="labNumber" prefHeight="14.0" prefWidth="73.0" text="0">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Cambria" size="11.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: I don't use eclipse, but maybe add the fxml to scene before calling controller.

Comment: This class is managing switching between different FXML files, and this code work for every other FXML in project so code must be okay... What I have done now is I created new FXML and controller class in target project and allmost copied everything from old project... It works now.

Comment: Make sure the FXML has been exported to the build directory (might not have happened if you copied these from one project to another). If not, you may need to clean and rebuild the project (from the "Project..." menu).